# Firebase - RecyclerView shows only one image multiple times

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

This is my java class

```
private String locations;
private String images;

public ItemData(){

}

public ItemData(String locations, String images){

    this.locations = locations;
    this.images = images;

}

public String getLocations() {
    return locations;
}

public void setLocations(String locations) {
    this.locations = locations;
}

public String getImages() {
    return images;
}

public void setImages(String images) {
    this.images = images;
   }

}
```

This is the Main Activity where I get datasnapshots from firebase.

```
    itemData = new ItemData();
    rv = findViewById(R.id.recycler);
    rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    data = new ArrayList<>();


    adapter = new RecyclerAdapter(data);
    rv.setAdapter(adapter);

}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    imageRef = database.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(userid).child("images");

    imageRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for (DataSnapshot mData : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                String mImages = mData.getValue(String.class);
                itemData.setImages(mImages);

                data.add(itemData);

            }

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
```

What I'm trying to do is show the images saved in the "images" key: urlImages1, urlImages2, urlImages3 for example.   But running the application only shows the same image in the size of the `recyclerview`. Very grateful for your help

**EDIT:**

```
public class RecyclerAdapter  extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ItemDataViewHolder>{

List<ItemData> data;


public RecyclerAdapter(List<ItemData> data) {
    this.data = data;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ItemDataViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_recycler, parent, false);
    ItemDataViewHolder holder = new ItemDataViewHolder(view);
         return holder;


}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ItemDataViewHolder holder, int position) {

    ItemData itemData = data.get(position);
    holder.location.setText(itemData.getLocations());

    Picasso.get().load(itemData.getImages())
            .rotate(270).into(holder.imageView);

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return data.size();
}


public static class ItemDataViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

ImageView imageView;
TextView title, location;
public ItemDataViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);

    imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rImageView);
    title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rTitleTv);
    location = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rDescriptionTv);
}
}

}
```

UPDATE: 
I want to show the data of "images" and "locations" in an adapter. How do I get the reference of the two keys in the same eventlistener?

"Users" : {

```
"X7aVfZH5oZbIaeyLm9FAjOSr5Gd2" : {
  "images" : {
    "urlImages1" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/anthiefy.appspot.com/o/X7aVfZH5oZbIaeyLm9FAjOSr5Gd2%2FImages%2FImg1.jpg?alt=media&token=e26fd6a2-2be7-4a01-920e-0aed1fe06436",
    "urlImages2" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/anthiefy.appspot.com/o/X7aVfZH5oZbIaeyLm9FAjOSr5Gd2%2FImages%2FImg2.jpg?alt=media&token=40165918-3b46-4b22-b0ef-255965b7855d",
    "urlImages3" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/anthiefy.appspot.com/o/X7aVfZH5oZbIaeyLm9FAjOSr5Gd2%2FImages%2FImg3.jpg?alt=media&token=cfd7d00d-9b1a-44fd-80d4-a2947f7de743",
    "urlImages4" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/anthiefy.appspot.com/o/X7aVfZH5oZbIaeyLm9FAjOSr5Gd2%2FImages%2FImg4.jpg?alt=media&token=995419a7-70f7-4330-b046-d06a4d54453e",
    "urlImages6" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/anthiefy.appspot.com/o/X7aVfZH5oZbIaeyLm9FAjOSr5Gd2%2FImages%2FImg6.jpg?alt=media&token=ee6f566a-a9e5-4e8f-9d53-64d3f3bc97a6",
    "urlImages7" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/anthiefy.appspot.com/o/X7aVfZH5oZbIaeyLm9FAjOSr5Gd2%2FImages%2FImg7.jpg?alt=media&token=883a3321-fbba-49bd-aae3-14b005b4cc5b"
  },
  "locations" : {
    "locations1" : "14.2830817 -89.7263953",
    "locations2" : "14.2661424 -89.7220017",
    "locations3" : "14.2846352 -89.7251991",
    "locations4" : "14.2684987 -89.7266704",
    "locations5" : "14.2684987 -89.7266704",
    "locations6" : "14.2684987 -89.7266704",
    "locations7" : "14.2684987 -89.7266704"
```

Comment: please share RecyclerAdapter class code it will help

Comment: @bk7 please, check the update

Comment: trying changing this RecyclerAdaper class declaration "public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ItemDataViewHolder>"   and remove static keyword in ItemDataViewHolder class

Comment: thanks, but it still does not work

Comment: adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); is called in onStart where have you  decleared RecyclerAdapter in onCreate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello make the following changes it should work fine.

```
 imageRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for (DataSnapshot mData : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                String mImages = mData.getValue(String.class);
               ItemData itemDataOne = new ItemData();
                itemDataOne .setImages(mImages);

                data.add(itemDataOne );

            }

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
```

Explaination: the problem was you were creating the ItemData Only once and setting it in loop. In Java Object (ItemData ) is passByReference type so when you add it to a list a reference is added and since only one object was created the same reference was being added and value was set to last data.

Comment: I have another problem. I want to get data from different keys. the "images" key contains 10 values ​​and the "locations" key contains 10 values. how do I get them to show them in the same position of the adapter?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more, are location and image url are different list?

Comment: you can add two listeners and combine both into one later in code or better option would be to change firebase structure to items:[{"image":"imageurl","location":"1234"}] and add a single listner.

Comment: It gives me this error: Failed to convert value of type java.util.HashMap to String

Comment: I'm not using HashMap. this error occurs when i changed firebase structure. Can you give an example how do i get data as shown in the update?